# US Passport - Laminated Photo has a white blemish

Tags: passports

I got my US passport a couple of months back and I just noticed that the laminated photo has a "white" small blemish/speck/missing spot. It's almost as if they "closed" the page too soon after printing/creating it and that part stuck to the other page.

It's on the top right on my hair just after the hairline.

Will this be a problem with countries such as the Bahamas? I have a passport card which doesn't have that blemish but I don't think I can go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Passports get damaged all the time with regular use; they are not the most sturdy things.

Unless it has severe damage, you can't see the photo or identifications, or it's missing pages, it should be OK.

(bold by me)

"If your passport has been significantly damaged, especially the book cover or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will need to apply for a new passport.  Damage that might require you to replace your passport includes water damage, a significant tear, unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a hole punch, or other injuries.

**Normal "wear and tear" of a U.S. passport is expected and likely does not count as "damage.**"  For instance normal wear includes the bend of a passport after being carried in your back pocket or fanning of the visa pages after extensive opening and closing. "

See : https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/passport-help/faqs.html

Comment: I guess it is also worth noting that, if they really want to see an undamaged version of the picture, there is one stored in digital form on the chip in a US (and most other country's) e-Passport.